# BaseClass method tries to execute again after completing childclass method stuffs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, inheritance

I have a base class with Login test using TestNG for selenium script.

```
public class BaseClass{ 
    @Test
    public void validLogin() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(properties.getProperty("username"));
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys(properties.getProperty("password"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
        Reporter.log("===== Verify Valid login=====", true);
    }
}
```

I am trying to call base class test from Child Class test.

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
    @Test
    public void performSearch() {
        validLogin();
        Reporter.log("=====Logged-in=====", true);
        System.out.println("Perform further actions");
    }
}
```

When I run Child Class as TestNG Test, it successfully executes validLogin() from Base class. But after completing childclass Test, it is again tries to execute validLogin() from BaseClass.

Can you please help me out and let me know why it is trying to execute alidLogin() second time and how can I restrict this?

Comment: Because, it's marked as `@Test`. Remove an attribute and it's not going to be executed. Can you explain why do you need to have a base class at all? I'm not sure I understand your question, to be honest.

Comment: I tried to create login script in one base class and use it in any other class where login is required to avoid writing login script again and again. Anything wrong in the implementation here?